# It's naive of you to believe that. vs It's naive for you to believe that

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

> 1. It's naive of you to believe that.

Why do we use 'of' and what's the meaning of 'of' and why can't we use 'for'?

There are some cases that we use only 'of' such as "kin of you, nice of you, etc.

> 2. It's naive for you to believe that.

This one is wrong as per my knowledge. If I use 'for', what does ist sound to natives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase **of you** is part of numerous similar expressions, such as:

> silly/foolish of you,
> brave/courageous of you,
> smart of you

It's simply idiomatic - the way we speak - another way of saying that someone has behaved in a manner that is silly, brave, smart or whatever.

To say **naive for you** implies that the belief, action or whatever is naive, rather than the person concerned. So it's slightly less personal. But it's not common.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=naive+of+you%2Cnaive+for+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2019

Comment: I agree the last point, which I *think* is essentially what could distinguish #1 *It''s stupid **of** you to do that* from #2 *It''s stupid **for** you to do that* in certain contexts (where #1 could strongly imply *you already did the stupid thing*, but #2 might simply imply *it **would** be stupid **if you were to do it***). Or maybe they're completely unrelated implications, I dunno.